# user details as block with auto refresh

Tags: 7, views

I am new to drupal. I want to show a module that refresh every 3 seconds and displays the other existing user details with their photo graph .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Block Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) module.

> Block Refresh allows an administrator to configure a block to refresh
>   it's content in a given number of seconds. Block Refresh uses
>   jQuery/AJAX so the refresh happens "behind-the-scenes".

Comment: thank you @monyn=mirza i am confused about creating blog .is there any way to make it clear ?

Comment: enable blog module in modules page. `admin/modules`